# Stored procedures multiple filters - all filters in one procedure or separate into own procedures per filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure where I pass parameter with type of filter, and second parameter with value of filter. It can be game type, user type etc.

I want to filter data based on different type. If it is game type it should filter by game_name column(whatever it is passed as parameter), if user type by user type name.

I am wondering from perspective of design, is it better to put multiple case statements in one stored procedure or create each stored procedure for different filter type, which in the end I would end with 5-6 different stored procedures with same core sql(select statement).

Example of procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Reports_UserStatsDaily] @network       VARCHAR(9) = NULL, 
                                               @playerAddress VARCHAR(42) = NULL, 
                                               @year          INT = NULL, 
                                               @month         INT = NULL,
                                               @from VARCHAR(15) = null,
                                               @to VARCHAR(15) = null
AS 
  BEGIN 
      -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from 
      -- interfering with SELECT statements. 
      SET nocount ON; 

      -- Insert statements for procedure here 
      SELECT [playeraddress], 
             [network], 
             [rounds], 
             [sessions], 
             [handle], 
             [hold], 
             Datefromparts([year], [month], [day]) AS [Date] 
      FROM   [dbo].[userstatsdaily] 
      WHERE  ( @network IS NULL 
                OR ( network = Upper(@network) ) ) 
             AND ( @playerAddress IS NULL 
                    OR ( playeraddress = Upper(@playerAddress) ) ) 
             AND ( @year IS NULL 
                    OR [year] = @year ) 
             AND ( @month IS NULL 
                    OR [month] = @month ) 

             AND ( @from IS NULL 
                    OR ( Datefromparts([year], [month], [day]) BETWEEN 
                             Cast(@from AS DATETIME2) AND Cast(@to AS DATETIME2) 
                       ) 
                 ) 
            AND (len(Handle) > 9 or len(Hold) > 9)
      ORDER  BY [year] ASC, 
                [month] ASC, 
                [day] ASC 
  END
```

Problem here is, more filters I put, I put more optional parameters, and append in the end in WHERE clause. How to achieve separation of concerns in stored procedures?

Comment: This is what [Aaron Bertrand describes as "the kitchen sink" procedure](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/). That article and this one: [Building High Performance Stored Procedures](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/high-performance-procedures/) might be helpful for you.

Comment: Looks like a "Catch-all" query. Have a look at this article from Gail Shaw: https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: That makes sense, but original answer is to segregate or keep bunch of if elses and ANDS in one store procedure